# Passing parameters between forms in MS Access

Tags: forms, ms-access, vba, parameters

I have created a login form named login where the username is typed into the txtEmployee textbox, and I need to display the same in the second page in another form in MS Access.

Comment: Is the user name the same as the windows login user name? If so, you can get the name from: http://www.mvps.org/access/api/api0008.htm

Comment: Also, why do you need to display the user name, surely the user knows who they are? If you need the name for some other reason, you should say so, because there is more than one way to pass the information. For example, if the name is used to filter records, the Where argument of the OpenForm method is probably best.

Comment: This sounds like you've built a system with fake security. Why did you do that, instead of using either Jet ULS or Windows NTFS security or Active Directory?

Answer (score 29):

[`DoCmd.OpenForm`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa141520(v=office.10).aspx) allows you to pass an arbitrary value as the last parameter. This value can be accessed in the new form as [`Me.OpenArgs`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa160845(v=office.10).aspx):

```
' Invoked by some Button on the first form '
Sub GoToSecondPage()
    DoCmd.OpenForm "MySecondPage", acNormal, , , , , txtEmployee.Value
End Sub

' Second form '
Sub Form_Open(Cancel As Integer)
    If Not IsNull(Me.OpenArgs) Then
        lblShowEmployeeName.Value = Me.OpenArgs
    End If
End Sub
```

(Code example untested.)

Answer (score 9):

You can pass a delimited string as the OpenArgs parameter:

```
DoCmd.OpenForm FormName:="miscForm", OpenArgs:=paramstring
```

Here's a routine for processing a pipe-delimited string passed as the parameter to DoCmd.OpenForm:

```
Dim Pstring As Variant

If Len(Me.OpenArgs) > 0 Then
   Pstring = Split(Me.OpenArgs, "|")
   var1 = Pstring(0)
   <etc..>
End If
```

Comment: I generally see the need to do this as an indication of a design problem. That is, if you have to pass that much information to the form, you basically should be using some kind of structured way of doing so.

Comment: @David, Are you referring to a `struct` type variable?  I only use this for one form in my current Access app, so that I don't have to put stuff in the database before I bring up the form, and then again when I'm in the form.  I'm open to a better idea, I'm no Access form expert.

Comment: There are any number of ways of accomplishing this. One is to simply poke the data into the called form from the calling context. This can be done by opening the form with both acHidden and acDialog, and when you're done getting the data into the called form, you make it visible, which makes it modal and code execution in the calling context stops. I generally don't do that. I'm more likely to use a class module, but that's only profitable when you've got several attributes you need to pass, such as when filtering on multiple criteria.

Answer (score 4):

Personally I would pass them through the open arguments when opening the form. For example from form A your would write

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmB", , , , , acDialog,”Badger”
```

And then in the OnOpen event of form B you can capture what you have sent like this

```
Me.txtSomething=Me.OpenArgs
```

You can only pass one thing however What I do a lot is pass a pipe delimited string in the open arguments and then split that out.

Comment: Why are you opening with acDialog?

Comment: Well that example was taken from like a popup form so I wanted it to be modal, this of course can be removed if the OP just wants a normal form

Answer (score 0):

A couple ideas...

Use the AfterUpdate event on the login username field to write the name to a global variable, then populate the field on the second page with the OnLoad event.

Or, if you plan on leaving the log in form open at all times you could set the default value of the field directly to =[Forms]![LogInForm]![UserName]

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a public function which stores &/or retrieves a global variable that you store after the first form is executed?  This would allow you to not only use it on one or more forms, but also as criteria within a query (for example, to return records which match the user name you've stored).

I agree this is "fake" security, but there also times when it's sufficient for your needs.  I've implemented this before, where I match the environment string username to an entry in a user table.

BTW, I refer to this feature as personalization, not security.

Just a thought.

Comment: I would never use a global for this. Instead, I'd use a STATIC variable inside the function that returns the value, and if it's not set, it would open the form to collect the information. This would mean it's both self-healing and safe from being altered elsewhere in code.