# VBA update public array from userform

Tags: vba, multidimensional-array, excel, parameter-passing, userform

I have a VBA Sub that create and handle an array:

```
Option Base 1
Public myArr(20, 10) As Variant

Sub Stackoverflow()
Dim x, y As Integer
    'Put some values to array (only in the first 15 rows)
    For x = 1 To 15
        For y = 1 To 10
            myArr(x, y) = (x * y + 8)
        Next y
    Next x
End Sub
```

Then there is a userform with a commandbutton that should be able to handle the array myArr.

```
Private Sub commandbutton_Click()
Dim a, b As Integer
    'Put some other values in the remaining rows
    For a = 16 To 20
        For b = 1 To 10
            myArr(a, b) = (a * b + 3)
        Next b
    Next a
End Sub
```

How can I pass the array to the userform? And how the Sub can view the updated array?
Thanks

Comment: Currently you are updating the end portion of the array from the UserForm. Isn't the code working for you? It worked fine for me

Comment: Because 'myArr' is public, you dont need to pass it as parameter to the form; you can just use it.  Because it is public, it is allways available to be used (what values are contained inside the array is another story).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code worked perfectly for me once I had completed it.  I can only assume you do not know how to call the userform.

I copied your `Stackoverflow()` to a module without changes.

To the same module I added:

```
Sub Main()

  Dim RowMyArr As Long
  Dim ColMyArr As Long

  Load UserForm1

  Call Stackoverflow

  UserForm1.Show

  Debug.Print "    ";
  For ColMyArr = LBound(myArr, 1) To UBound(myArr, 1)
    Debug.Print Right("   " & ColMyArr, 4) & " ";
  Next
  Debug.Print

  For RowMyArr = LBound(myArr, 2) To UBound(myArr, 2)
    Debug.Print Right("  " & RowMyArr, 3) & " ";
    For ColMyArr = LBound(myArr, 1) To UBound(myArr, 1)
      Debug.Print Right("   " & myArr(ColMyArr, RowMyArr), 4) & " ";
    Next
    Debug.Print
  Next

End Sub
```

I created a user form and did not change the default name from UserForm1.  I added a button, named it `commandbutton` and copied your code to the form's code area.  Before the `End Sub`, I added `Unload UserForm1` to close and exit the form.

I ran Main and the following was output to the immediate window:

```
       1    2    3    4    5    6    7    8    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20 
  1    9   10   11   12   13   14   15   16   17   18   19   20   21   22   23   19   20   21   22   23 
  2   10   12   14   16   18   20   22   24   26   28   30   32   34   36   38   35   37   39   41   43 
  3   11   14   17   20   23   26   29   32   35   38   41   44   47   50   53   51   54   57   60   63 
  4   12   16   20   24   28   32   36   40   44   48   52   56   60   64   68   67   71   75   79   83 
  5   13   18   23   28   33   38   43   48   53   58   63   68   73   78   83   83   88   93   98  103 
  6   14   20   26   32   38   44   50   56   62   68   74   80   86   92   98   99  105  111  117  123 
  7   15   22   29   36   43   50   57   64   71   78   85   92   99  106  113  115  122  129  136  143 
  8   16   24   32   40   48   56   64   72   80   88   96  104  112  120  128  131  139  147  155  163 
  9   17   26   35   44   53   62   71   80   89   98  107  116  125  134  143  147  156  165  174  183 
 10   18   28   38   48   58   68   78   88   98  108  118  128  138  148  158  163  173  183  193  203
```

I have not checked the values but I assume they are correct.

Comment: Your answer is as simple as what I mean! Thanks so much!

Answer (score -1):

Its a public array, accessible from any form in your application . . . why do you need to pass it anyway? 
This one describes how to pass parameter to forms in access vba.

[Passing parameters between forms in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474568/passing-parameters-between-forms-in-ms-access)