# Show/Hide different Controls for different Users MS Access Form

Tags: vba, ms-access, controls, show-hide

I've designed a login form in MS Access. I've different user roles and want to display different controls to at different user logins. For instance, if an admin is logged in, the controls should be different and a normal user should be able to use different controls.

The vba code I've written for SignIn button on click is as follows (this code is for `Login_Form`):

```
Private Sub Btn_SignIn_Click()

IF Me.Txt_UserID.Value = "admin" AND Me.Txt_Password = "123admin"  
                                 AND Me.Cmbo_UserRole.Value = "DBA"  
THEN

    MsgBox "Welcome to RMS", vbOKOnly, "Logged in as Admin!"

    DoCmd.OpenForm "Main_Form"
    --How can I show/hide controls here at Main_Form
End If
```

`Main_Form` has different controls, but I'm unable to access `Main_Form` controls inside `Btn_SignIn_Click()` function. So that, I might be able to show or hide controls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
with forms("main_form")
   !control1.visible = true
   !control2.visible = true
end with
```

If there are lots of such controls, you can also use

```
for each ctl in form_main_form
   ctl.visible = true
next ctl
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Procedure to validate if the user is admin or not.
For example:

```
Private Sub Main_Form_Load(UserLevel as String)

  If UserLevel = "admin" Then
     Your code here to show controls.
  End If
End Sub
```

I suggest to hide the controls by default that should be used only by the Admin.

Then you can call the UserForm sending parameters as other solver in other question:

> [Passing parameters between forms in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474568/passing-parameters-between-forms-in-ms-access)