# Opening new form to add customer order

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2013

I have a fairly straight forward DB, tblCustomers, tblDeliveries, frmcustomers and frmorders. Customers and Deliveries are already set up in a one to many relationship. If I place frmorders into frmCustomers as a subform, I can do what I want but I really don’t like the way that works with having to adjust visibility of the subform repeatedly throughout depending on what the user is doing, etc. I am trying to find out if there is a way to open frmDeliveries as a separate form ready to accept a new order for whatever customer was open on frmCustomers. I’ve tried setting a where clause on form open to pass the CusID from tblCustomers to the Customer_ID in tblDeliveries which frmDeliveries is built on, but it’s not passing it over, that field is blank when the new form opens. The code I am using is

`Private Sub btnNewOrder_Click()
DoCmd.OpenForm “frmNewOrder”, _
WhereCondition = “Customer_ID= & Me.txtCusID
End Sub`

is it the code or is it just something that’s not possible, that it can only be done via SubForm? thank you.

Comment: Cannot pass a value to another form that way. For one method review [Passing parameters between forms in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474568/passing-parameters-between-forms-in-ms-access).

Comment: On second thought, can pass value with WHERE argument - sort of. Form's Filter property will be set with criteria. Form can read its Filter property and parse value from string. However, there are easier ways to do what you want.

Comment: use the 3rd paramter - the where clause. Your example uses the 2nd, and that is incorrect.  using the 3rd param (where clause) will work as you have and this assumes the form you are launching has record(s) with a matching customer_ID. If you going to allow add mode then you need to pass the customer id as the "last" parameter (args), and then in the form new order, you have to "set" the customer_ID value to that value - use the on-insert event and me.Customer_ID = me.OpenArgs