# To get Auto Number field value from table in MS Access

Tags: ms-access

How to get a Auto Number column value from a table in MS Access. I need the value to store it in another table.
For ex,

```
Table1:    Table2:
Id value    CId    City
1   aaa     1      abc
2   bbb
```

Id in Table1 is auto numbered, where as CId in Table2 is not and note that **not** all values in table1 are present in table2. I'm creating a form to store value, city in respective tables. How do I get the auto number value so that I can store it as CId in table2.
So, if new value is entered it would take the Id 3, I require the Id 3 to store in Table2

Also, I can't go with Form Wizard option as, I dont want all the records in the table to be visible. I just require a blank form to save new data.
Please help me out in this. Thank you

Comment: Easiest approach is a form/subform arrangement. Otherwise, there are several ways to pass data between forms and a common topic. Do research and when you have specific code with issue, post question. Explore OpenArgs, TempVars, and directly setting value of control on another form. I never use form design wizard and it's use is irrelevant. You can always change form properties after it's created. If you want form only for entry of new record then set its DataEntry property to Yes.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing parameters between forms in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3474568/passing-parameters-between-forms-in-ms-access)

Comment: `So, if new value is entered it would take the Id 3, I require the Id 3 to store in Table2` All new value will be stored to `table2`? What about `INSERT INTO....` for `table1` then `DMAX()` to get last value from auto id field and then another `INSERT INTO...` for table2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used Unbound textbox `Text1` to run below codes.

```
Private Sub cmdSQLRun_Click()
Dim MyAutoNumber As Long

    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table1(MyValue) VALUES('" & Me.Text1 & "')"
    'MyValue is value field of your example.
    MyAutoNumber = DMax("ID", "Table1")
    CurrentDb.Execute "INSERT INTO Table2(CID) VALUES(" & MyAutoNumber & ")"
    'CID is table2 field name.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion, It worked! I have another issue, hope you can help me out in it. From a Form I'm passing a input 'string' parameter value to a query. Its not resulting any record. In the column criteria I have used - Like "& [Forms]![Form1]![txtinput]" . Looks like the text box is passing some null value, so could you suggest how else can I correct to fetch the required result.

Comment: Just use `Like ([Forms]![Form1]![txtinput])`

Comment: Glad to know it helped you!

Comment: Apologies for posting more questions, first time worked fine. Later when I closed and tried again the text box is not passing any value. Its just null. And so no record is fetched. Can you let me know where am I going wrong.

Comment: Can you please check your data if there any extra spaces or something else.